# webpack external not loading module

Tags: webpack, bundler, es6-modules

I'm making a library wherein I need to specify `React` as a peer dependency.  So I specify it as I've seen documented:

```
externals: {
    react: "react"
  },
```

I add it as a peer dependency so that its installed in my depending app.  But I wind up with:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: react is not defined

At this point I've spent over two hours googling the problem and have made no progress.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm fairly sure that React exposes itself as `React` and not `react`, identifier names are case sensitive. (i.e. `externals: { react: "React" }`)
2. Make sure that you actually have a `<script src=""></script>` on your HTML page which actually includes React to begin with.